# Couldn't resolve the dependency for elasticsearch library for spark-submit py files

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to stream data from flat files into elastic search using structured streaming (pyspark)

Spark - 2.4.6

Scala - 2.11.0

Hadoop - 2.7

While trying to submit the job by specifying dependency like below it works,

```
spark-submit --packages org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:7.7.1 FileStructuredStreaming_ES.py
```

**Problem is:**
My production environment I cannot use --packages (restricted to the internet). I am trying to find the jar, which can be moved into the cluster rather than using --packages but couldn't achieve it, tried will all possible ways like

--py-files / --archives / --jars

Following way of submitting the spark job fails with follwoing error:

```
spark-submit --py-files elasticsearch-hadoop-7.7.1.jar /workspace/scripts/pyspark/FileStructuredStreaming_ES.py
```

**Error Trace**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.elasticsearch.spark.sql. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:657)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:307)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:634)
    ... 12 more
```

Am I missing anything here, is there a way to find out which library / jar i need to use? What i am using is an official jar?

Comment: You mean the jar you got from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/7.7.1/ does not resolve your issue whan you pass it using `--jars`?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I tried with --archives (whole zip), --jars (specific on required jars), --py-files(on specific jars). I am not sure what i am doing wrong!!